# OsiSoft AF SDK 2018 SP2 with .NET 5 Application

Tags: osisoft

I have an application that was upgraded to .NET 5.  However, the OsiSoft AF SDK is still compiled in .NET.  I'm getting errors as such:

Method not found: 'System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl()'.

Is there a way to run AF SDK .NET in .NET Core/.NET 5 applications ?  My understanding is AF SDK does not support .NET Core/.NET 5 as of yet.

Comment: No solutions for you, unfortunately - but here's the [OSIsoft Feedback Idea](https://feedback.osisoft.com/forums/555145-pi-developer-technologies/suggestions/40291651-add-net-core-support-for-af-sdk) that needs to be voted on to flag this as a priority for customers. I've added a vote for you. It does already seem to be the top-voted idea, so I'm surprised it hasn't moved in the past year. Also more thoughts [in the comments of this PISquare post](https://pisquare.osisoft.com/s/question/0D51I00004UHkBkSAL/will-af-sdk-be-supported-in-net-5-year-end-2020)

Comment: Depending on what exactly your application needs to do there may be other integration routes using alternative components (e.g. PI WebAPI?). I'd suggest flagging this to somebody in your organisation who can raise a ticket directly with OSIsoft / AVEVA for their view.